# Google Sheets multiple conditional formatting for date range and text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply multiple conditional formatting to a google sheets column. I want two conditions:

**A Column** needs to equal/contain "Accepted" from a dropdown cell

**B Column** needs to contain a future due date that is within 14 days to today

I want to highlight C column based on those two conditions being met with a priority flag for Accepted and has a due date within 14 days of today. Here's what I've got so far:

Custom conditional formatting for column C is:

```
=(A="Assigned")+(B<=TODAY()+14)
```

What I'd like to see is:

```
=(A="Assigned")+(B<=TODAY()+14)+(B>=TODAY())
```

But it's not working. Either I have to specify the exact reference columns (ex: A5) which aren't what I want, or it's not working at all. Any recommendations?

[image: Google Sheets Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - just get it right for the first row (say row 2) and the other rows will follow by relative addressing:

```
=and(A2="Accepted",B2>=today(),B2<=today()+14)
```

[image]

If you want to apply the conditional formatting to more than one column, put in dollar signs to anchor the columns:

```
and($A2="Accepted",$B2>=today(),$B2<=today()+14)
```

Comment: You're welcome! (Plz tick accepted box if it works for you)

Answer (score 1):

you were close... this is what would work as well:

```
=($A2="Assigned")*($B2<=TODAY()+14)*($B2>=TODAY())
```